# Initial configuration of Linksys WRT1900ACS router via remote console over local wired network without Internet access

Tags: router, ssh, ethernet, console

Here is my question: is it possible to perform the initial configuration (from factory presets) of a Linksys WRT1900ACS router via SSH over a local ethernet network (i.e. no WiFi) which is not connected to the Internet?

A more detailed explanation follows; it almost sounds like a brain teaser or a lateral-thinking puzzle, but this is my situation. I have a Linksys WRT1900ACS router - just taken out of the box, nothing done to it. I'm only going to use it to add a small subnetwork to a larger private network. The network is completely private (no logical or physical internet connections) and completely wired (no wireless connectivity). Moreover, none of the computers that I can connect it to have wireless capability and the only user interface to any of them is a text-based console. So I can run a TUI (Text-based User Interface) web-browser (such as elinks) but not a GUI web-browser (such as Firefox). Note that in my initial phrasing of the question (above) I specified connecting to the router remotely via SSH, because that would be preferable, but actually I can directly access the physical console of the connected host if that helps (although I can't imagine how it would).

I tried searching the web and I even tried calling Linksys technical support, but to no avail.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is a so-called Smart WiFi router/AP which means it can ONLY be managed through the Linksys cloud-solution, which is GUI only and requires an live Internet connection to work.
(Smart means: Smart for Linksys, not for power-users.)

So this won't work.

The good news: You can run OpenWRT on it, which has SSH access as well.
But you are going to need another computer system with GUI to do the 1st time setup, to the point you have OpenWRT installed and the SSH connection enabled. (It is off by default if memory serves.)

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I'm going to leave this up for a bit in case there's some secret solution that someone has found, but otherwise I guess I'll have to accept it.

Comment: I want to give you bonus points for suggesting OpenWRT, even if the asker can't actually proceed with that install either.

Comment: OpenWrt was already the plan. ;)